# Show list of page titles wikimedia

Tags: wikimedia

I want to show a list of the titles of all pages in a wiki on the home page.  I can't find anything in the documentation, there doesn't seem to be a wikimedia forum.  The only question I can find on SO hasn't been answered.

Any suggestions?

Comment: LOL, closed after almost 10 years

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found an extension that does exactly what I want.

[http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension:DynamicPageList_(Wikimedia)](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension%3aDynamicPageList_%28Wikimedia%29)

Answer (score 0):

Wikipedia allows you to view any page in XML. Say you want the wiki of the Apple Macintosh. The regular wiki URL is http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Macintosh if you take the end (after wiki/ i.e. "Macintosh" and put it instead of the X's in this url: [http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Special:Export/XXXXXXX](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Special%3aExport/XXXXXXX) it'll generate the XML of that page which you can then parse out.

Hope this helps :)